# Can't find single property and navigate related data without IQueryable all properties

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I have relational data properties on my objects that I would like to access:

```
public class Person
{
   public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; private set; } = new Collection<Address>();
   ...
}

public class Address
{
   ...
   public int PersonId { get; set; }
   public Person Person { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

The only way I have found to traverse, or even exercise, this navigation property without lazy loading (and pulling in proxies, etc) is to eager load it:

```
var entityList = await _context.Persons.Where(p => p.Id == request.PersonId)
    .Include(p => p.Addresses)
    .ToListAsync();
```

which is inconvenient because now I always have to do the following in order to cleanly access the class (and its properties):

```
var person = entityList.FirstOrDefault();
```

Every example in the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager):

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
    .ToList();
```

they grab every blog entity, instead of just a single one, before loading in related data.

I can't explicitly load because that relies on the [`public virtual EntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity)`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/106ac1ab4f0948ad52ca7318d376b1def9148321/src/EFCore/DbContext.cs#L915) which I can't accesses via my injected `DbContext` interface.

Is there a cleaner way to do this without the IQueryable `where` expression? I simply want to find my single entity and navigate its properties.

Comment: you cannot do `_context.Persons..Include(p => p.Addresses).ToListAsync();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I think you are confusing eager/lazy loading with the LINQ execution methods. For something like this:

```
var entityList = await _context.Persons.Where(p => p.Id == request.PersonId)
    .Include(p => p.Addresses)
    .ToListAsync();
var person = entityList.FirstOrDefault();
```

You really just want 1 person with their addresses, then use:

```
var person = await _context.Persons
    .Include(p => p.Addresses)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == request.PersonId);
```

This will fetch the person with its related addresses. It would be better to use `SingleAsync` rather than the "OrDefault" variant if you expect there to always be a record. (Throw an exception if an invalid PersonId is sent)

`Include` determines the eager loading. `ToList` just tells Linq to expect possible multiple matching rows. Where you might have encountered issues was trying to use `Find` on the `DbSet` and it resorting to lazy-loading for the Addresses collection.

The `First` methods should only ever be used in conjunction with an `OrderBy` clause where you expect possible multiple matching rows, to ensure the query is predictable.

Comment: Wow - you nailed it precisely. Not only did this work, you were right in predicting that I misunderstood the loading and LINQ execution methods. You were also on-point in guessing that I had been trying to use `Find` and couldn't reason out as to why that didn't work and, until now, I couldn't find a single example like yours. Thank you so much; I've been stuck on this for hours.